# Make another form that will display a list(autocomplete) and will be used as a value for selected fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms the first one has a autocomplete field(laborer names//from mysql table),and input field for manually entering date. Another is a form below containing fields to be filled by the user.

```
<form class="well form-search">
    Date of Payment:
    <?php if($sf_user->hasCredential('PAYMENT')): ?>
        <input type="text" class="field2 required" size="15" name="date_of_payment_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $sf_params->get('date_of_payment_'.$l['id'], date('Y-m-d')) ?>" placeholder="payment date"/>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    Laborer: <input type="hidden" class="laborers" id="laborer_id_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" name="collector_id_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $sf_params->get('collector_id_'.$l['id']) ?>" />
    <input rel="<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" type="text" class="field2 required laborer_autocomplete" size="15" name="laborer_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $sf_params->get('laborer_'.$l['id'])?>" id="laborer_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" placeholder="laborerr"/>
        <?php if(isset($fieldErrors['laborer_id_'.$l['id']])): ?>
            <div class="error">
                <?php echo $fieldErrors['laborer_id_'.$l['id']] ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Go</button>
</form>
```

The second form

```
<form action="<?php echo //?>" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure? This cannot be undone!')">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="personid" style="width:5px;">#</th>
                <th>Days</th>
                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Date of Payment</th>//I want this to hide
                <th>Laborer</th>//I want this to hide
                <th>Amount Received</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($works as $i=>$l): ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo ($i%2==0)?'even':'odd' ?>">
                    <td class="personid"></td>
                    <td>PHP<?php echo number_format($l['days'], 2) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $l['term'] ?> days</td>
                    <td>
                        Date of Payment (YYYY-MM-DD)<br />
                        <input type="text" class="field2 required" size="15" name="date_of_payment_<?php //echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php// echo $sf_params->get('date_of_payment_'.$l['id'], date('Y-m-d')) ?>" placeholder="payment date"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="laborers" id="laborer_id_<?php //echo $l['id'] ?>" name="laborer_id_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $sf_params->get('laborer_id_'.$l['id']) ?>" />
                        <input rel="<?php// echo $l['id'] ?>" type="text" class="field2 required collectors_autocomplete" size="15" name="laborer_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $sf_params->get('laborer_'.$l['id'])?>" id="laborer_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>" placeholder="laborerr"/>
                        <?php if(isset($fieldErrors['laborer_id_'.$l['id']])): ?>
                            <div class="error">
                                <?php echo $fieldErrors['laborer_id_'.$l['id']] ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php //endif; ?>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table> <!--end table-->
```

Instead of manual input for laborer and date of payment fields in the second form, is it possible to automatically populate these fields by filling the first form?

Comment: Are both forms on the same page? Also, you said a laborer is picked via a dropdown... your markup shows a text box (input type=text)?

Comment: I already updated my question.Both forms are on the same page.And laborer is picked via a autocomplete list

Comment: In your second form, an array of _something_ is being rendered as table rows. Will the laborer and date of payment values be duplicated in every row?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be duplicated in every row @jbarreiros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the javascript "blur" event, we can copy the data from one field to any other element on the page. The "blur" event means the field no longer has focus. That is, the user tabbed to the next field or clicked some other element on the page.

Not sure what your browser requirements are, so I'm going to suggest [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). Here is a simple example:

**html:**

```
<!-- form snippet -->
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="">

<!-- destination -->
<input type="hidden" name="field1b" class="show-field1">
<input type="hidden" name="field1c" class="show-field1">
<p class="show-field1"></p>
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#field1").blur(function(event) {
    // jquery sets "this" to the element handling the event; i.e. "field1"
    // "value" is a standard property on <input> elements
    var value = this.value;

    // next, select your targets
    var copyTo = $(".show-field1");

    // if copying to a form element
    copyTo.val(value);

    // if copying to a DOM element
    copyTo.text(value);
});
```

I hope that helps. I created a jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/jbarreiros/o5cuv2nt/.